# Arraylist and if statement not working

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, bukkit

I am making a bukkit plugin and it has an option to toggle. This is the code I used to make the toggle. In game, the only response is OFF, when it should toggle between ON and OFF. Please help!

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("togglegift") && sender instanceof Player){

        Player Tplayer = (Player) sender;

        if(players.contains(Tplayer.getName())) {
            Tplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[BapGift] " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Gifts Toggled" + ChatColor.GREEN + " ON");
            players.remove(Tplayer.getName());

        } else {
        players.add(Tplayer.getName());
        Tplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[BapGift] " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Gifts Toggled" + ChatColor.RED + " OFF");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well you are declaring and initializing an empty list and then you call `contains` on it.. So obvioulsy, the if condition will never be true.

Comment: @ZouZou in the `else` part OP's adding elements to the list.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Each time the method is called, the list is redeclared and reinitialized. So even if you add an element in the else statement, that won't change anything.

Comment: Extending @ZouZou's answer: You may not declare the List players inside the method. Put it in the class declaration.

Comment: @ZouZou then that's the only issue. And it should be a `Set<String>` rather than a `List<String>`.

Comment: That name `Tplayer` is hurting my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Like @ZouZou mentioned in the comments, your list `players` is every time recreated, when your method is called.

Because of that, it is always empty and the player's name will never be contained in it.

To solve the problem, move the declaration of the list `players` out of your method.

```
public class ThaClassInWhichYourMethodIsDeclared {
    private ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();


    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {


        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("togglegift") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player Tplayer = (Player) sender;

            if (players.contains(Tplayer.getName())) {
                Tplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[BapGift] " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Gifts Toggled" + ChatColor.GREEN + " ON");
                players.remove(Tplayer.getName());

            } else {
                players.add(Tplayer.getName());
                Tplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[BapGift] " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Gifts Toggled" + ChatColor.RED + " OFF");
            }
        }

}
```

And to include @LuiggiMendoza's comment, it would look like this:

```
public class ThaClassInWhichYourMethodIsDeclared {
    private Set<String> players = new HashSet<String>();


    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("togglegift") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player Tplayer = (Player) sender;

            if (players.contains(Tplayer.getName())) {
                Tplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[BapGift] " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Gifts Toggled" + ChatColor.GREEN + " ON");
                players.remove(Tplayer.getName());

            } else {
                players.add(Tplayer.getName());
                Tplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[BapGift] " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Gifts Toggled" + ChatColor.RED + " OFF");
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It purely depends on your creation of the class instance.
If the class object is created only once, then the arraylist instance variable can be created outside the function. If the class object is created more than once, then again the arraylist is initialized twice.

Answer (score -3):

You must move your List as **static** List. In your class declaration as **class** scope (or **instance** scope as private only). If you don't, as sayed @ZouZou, the list is only locally used so created in method scope.

```
public class <YOUR_CLASS_NAME> extends JavaPlugin {

    /**
     * Declare your list as class scope.
     */
    private static final List<String> PLAYERS;

    // Static block is used to do not instanciate variable as attribute declaration.
    static {
        PLAYERS = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("togglegift") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player Tplayer = (Player) sender;

            if (PLAYERS.contains(Tplayer.getName())) {
                Tplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[BapGift] " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Gifts Toggled" + ChatColor.GREEN + " ON");
                PLAYERS.remove(Tplayer.getName());

            } else {
                PLAYERS.add(Tplayer.getName());
                Tplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[BapGift] " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Gifts Toggled" + ChatColor.RED + " OFF");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Whats the point of using a static list, when you have only an `onCommand()` method, which uses it, and it's not static?

Comment: No, static is most probably wrong. Or at least bad practice. The method is non-static and the field shouldn't be static either.

Comment: The approach is fine. However, I would not declare the variable as `static`, just as field of the class.

Comment: @MPirious the fact that the `static` variable is used in a non-static method doesn't mean it's bad.

Comment: Yeah static is not an obligation, but on Bukkit the plugin (the class) is used once by server instance. It is loaded on server start. Thats why I chose it.

Comment: We don't know how this class is being used, or even what it is.  There might be multiple instances of this class each time the program runs, each requiring their own list of players.  Making this static would be a mistake.

Comment: @DavidWallace We know how it works, I just explained. It is used as server starting. The class must have one only instance by JVM. The **static** can be remove, but for a Bukkit plugin, the behaviour still fine.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know, that Bukkit loads the classes as single instances.
@LuiggiMendoza: Making a field static and using it (only!) in non-static methods is a "code smell". You restrict the use of your class. If you can use a class just once and this is not clear (e.g. private constructor) it is not intuitive. And this is usually bad in programming.

Comment: All we know from the question is that this class is being used somewhere in the plugin.  We don't know whether it's a singleton or not.  You're essentially setting up a global variable, which is a bad idea for reasons that have been written about for decades.

Comment: @MPirious I know that. But your argument was invalid for me. In fact, I support DavidWallace's comment.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza
I think, we need to differentiate between what is possible/useful in that specific context and in general. I don't want to teach other developers (like you, DavidWallace, or Nemolovich I assume) how to program.
In my opinion it is important to show even beginners "best practices". Just imagine someone reading the answer and using it in another environment, where it is not guaranteed, that there is just one instance.
It is not my intention to offend anyone. I'm sure everybody here knows the way it works!

Comment: Indeed. But look at the expected behaviour: The plugin is here to enable/disable a player information ('togglegift'). As architect point of view, the players list is as application (server) scope. The player information in cascade too. So if you want switch the state of the 'tooglegift', the list of players 'toggled' is in application scope (not plugin instance).

Comment: @MPirious *I don't want to teach other developers (...) how to program* this is funny because when you post an answer here you're teaching something to the people around the world, and it's about programming. So yes, you become a kind of professor. Anyway, having this conversation is off-topic in this place. Just keep the good rate. And sure, don't think you cannot teach me something, I know you can do it.

Comment: @MPirious I totally agree with you. But here in the question it is specified the context and utilization of this code and what it expect to do.